# Calling Javascript function and django view function at the same time

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms

I am a django beginner, I was trying to call django view function and Javascript function at the same time through submit button in django form but django view is not calling.
Is there any way that I can call both functions at the same time?

Comment: Hi user12832372, Welcome to stackoverflow. can you describe what are you actually doing with both requests or you want to achieve

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve] and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `onclick` event on your submit button, but you'll have short period beetween click on submit button and page redirect. When Django redirects you to success page you wouldn't be able to access your function anymore.

```
 <form>
    {csrf_token}
    <button type="submit" onclick="yourFunction()">Button</button>
</form>
```

Comment: My function automatically disappears after pressing on submit how to manage it?